# Keeping text field and button inline responsively

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am trying to keep this text box and submit button in the same line. And I just wanna keep the submit button in the right side and occupying small width and rest of width to be occupied by the text field.

The problem I am trying to solve is, I want this to work good responsively. So that the text field's width adjusts as the screen is dragged.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline event-questions">
    <div class="event-questions-field">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ask a question..." style="width: 100%" type="text">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger question-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.event-questions {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.event-questions .question-submit.btn {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
}

.event-questions .question-submit.btn .event-questions {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.event-questions .question-submit.btn .event-questions .event-questions-field {
  width: 89%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float both items left. The button has a fixed width (of 100px), the width of the div is calculated with calc. Here are some examples of [calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/). Calc is not available in all browsers, check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) to see if your preferred browsers are supported. Here is my [solution in codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/OVKgrr).

CSS:

```
.event-questions {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.event-questions .question-submit.btn {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding: 6px 18px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.event-questions .event-questions-field {
    float: left;
    /* 100px of button width */
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```